# Understanding __call__ and list.sort(key)

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following code I am trying to understand:

```
>>> class DistanceFrom(object):
        def __init__(self, origin):
            self.origin = origin
        def __call__(self, x):
            return abs(x - self.origin)  

>>> nums = [1, 37, 42, 101, 13, 9, -20]
>>> nums.sort(key=DistanceFrom(10))
>>> nums
[9, 13, 1, 37, -20, 42, 101]
```

Can anyone explain how this works? As far as I have understood, `__call__` is what is called when `object()` is called - calling the object as a function.

What I don't understand is how `nums.sort(key=DistanceFrom(10))`. How does this work? Can anyone please explain this line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I have defined a function `DistanceFrom()` which can be used in a similar way to your class, but might be easier to follow

```
>>> def DistanceFrom(origin):
...     def f(x):
...         retval = abs(x - origin)
...         print "f(%s) = %s"%(x, retval)
...         return retval
...     return f
... 
>>> nums = [1, 37, 42, 101, 13, 9, -20]
>>> nums.sort(key=DistanceFrom(10))
f(1) = 9
f(37) = 27
f(42) = 32
f(101) = 91
f(13) = 3
f(9) = 1
f(-20) = 30
>>> nums
[9, 13, 1, 37, -20, 42, 101]
```

So you see that the object returned by `DistanceFrom` is *called* once for each item of `nums` and then `nums` is returned sorted in accordance with the returned values

Answer (score 8):

`__call__` in python allows a class to be run as if it's a function. You can try this out manually:

```
>>> dis = DistanceFrom(10)
>>> print dis(10), dis(5), dis(0)
0 5 10
>>>
```

What sort does is call that function for every item in your list and uses the returned value as sort key. In this example you'll get a list back with the items closest to 10 first, and the one further away more towards the end.

Comment: @user: Your answer was perfect, but I accepted gnibbler's answer since it would be beneficial to beginners in case they search for it.

Answer (score 4):

It sorts list `nums` in place using a `key` function object `DistanceFrom(10)`. It needs to be callable because `key` needs to be callable. The resulting output is sorted by their "remoteness" from 10, that is 9 is the closest value to 10, 101 is the farthest one.

After the object is initialised and passed as a `key` parameter to the `sort` method, on each iteration it will be called with the current value (that's what `x` is) and returned value would be used to determine `x`'s position in the resulting list.

Comment: How is this executed? I mean, DistanceFrom(10) sets self.origin = 10. After that?

Comment: "__ init __" is a constructor that gets called during creation of the Object key

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out to check whether I have understood it completely.

Answer (score 1):

When you call something that means you are expecting it to return a value.  When you create a class that has the `__call__` method defined, you are dictating that an instance of that class can behave as a function does.

For the purpose of this question, this:

```
class DistanceFrom(object):
        def __init__(self, origin):
            self.origin = origin
        def __call__(self, x):
            return abs(x - self.origin)
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
def distance_from(origin, other):
    return abs(other - origin)
```

As for the `key` argument to sort, here is your explanation straight from the Python documentation:

> *key* specifies a function of one
>   argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element:
>   `key=str.lower`. The default value is
>   None (compare the elements directly)

Answer (score 1):

The Python docs are quite good whenever I find I don't understand the fundamentals. I located these with google.

[The `key` parameter](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) is a function that sort will call on the elements of the list. I located this doc by googling `sort site:http://docs.python.org/` and then searching for `key=`.

[`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) is a function you can add to an object to make that object callable as if it were a function. I found this doc by googling `__call__ site:http://docs.python.org/` and then following the link to the doc for `__call__`.

Comment: I understand what they are, my question was specific for this example.